# Edit attribute tables with another table in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, arcgis-notebook

I have two tables and I need to update one based on the other. For this, I need to take two columns (idscap and spardcode) as the initial reference value and thus modify all the columns of the table.
Finally, I need you to save each of the records in a Notepad or Excel, since there are many records, the code may fail at some point and I need to have the information of where it left off and thus continue right there.

The code I have so far is the following, it is not generating an error but it is not processing what I really want either.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import re

# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Datos.gdb"

#definir tiempo
from timeit import default_timer
inicio = default_timer()

#Feature source and target
fSource = 'datosscap_temp1_origen'
fTarget = 'datosscap_temp1_destino'

#Fields source and target
sourceFields = ["idscap","sparcode", "iua", "ius", "iul"]
targetFields = ["ID_SCAP","CODIGO_SPARD", "IUA", "IUS", "IUL"]

#Iniciar edición
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()

#Cursor de búsqueda en datos de origen
def update():
    scursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fSource,sourceFields)
    cont = 0
    for r in scursor:
        cont += 1

        #actualización y condicional en datos de destino
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fTarget,targetFields, "ID_SCAP= %i" %(r[0])) as updateRows:
            
            for row in updateRows:
                updateRows.updateRow(r)
                
            if cont == 5:
                print("Se han ejecutado %s datos" %cont)
                break
                
            print(row, cont)
            
        fin = default_timer()
        time_min = (fin-inicio)/60
        print("Tiempo de ejecución: %0.3f minutos" %time_min)
                
                
    del updateRows

update()
edit.stopEditing (True)
```

Comment: Rather than using cursors within cursors I would suggest you explore doing a simple table join, update, then break join?

Comment: Nesting cursors is wasteful. With 64-bit Python you can just cache the whole SearchCursor in a dictionary and do a single UpdateCursor or Calculate field to populate values.